# Getting HTML Source with nested iframes using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to get the full HTML source as it shows up in Firefox (for example), **including the nested iframe contents** (even if there are nested iframes within the iframes).

Is there a way to do it in Selenium without having to write length recursions using `switch_to.frame()` and `switch_to.default_content()`?

I'm not sure it's relevant, but I would like to do this from Python.

Comment: No responses at all?